# Bootstrap + BootstrapVue. Как оптимизировать?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vue.js

Мы вроде бы избавляемся от jQuery и должны получить меньший размер .js файла, но в итоге он у меня получается ещё больше. Тоже самое и с .css т.к нужно подключать стили еще и от BootstrapVue. Какие советы будут по этому поводу?

В надежде на оптимизацию я подключаю отдельные компоненты BootstrapVue в моих компонентах. Скажи, насколько это правильный подход? Повлияет ли на оптимизацию тот факт, если подключать компоненты BootstrapVue глобально в главном app.js файле и если да, то в какую сторону?

Некоторые компоненты BootstrapVue не требуют js. То есть, такие компоненты просто генерируют определенные <\div> и только. Если сделать это руками без использования компонента, повлияет ли это на оптимизацию или в конечном итоге Vue от рендерит любой из этих вариантов одинаково?

Буду очень благодарен, если добавите от себя советы по оптимизации. В основном сайт будет просматриваться со старых мобильных устройств, поэтому любые советы будут полезны. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант импортировать из BottstrapVue только те компоненты которые вы используете

Comment: самый эффективный способ уменьшения итогового бандла - это начать использовать асинхронные компоненты, которые подгружаются только при необходимости

Comment: @Дмытрык вы об этом? component: () => import('./Foo.vue')

Comment: Да, об этом .....